# PowerBI Service Account granting duplicate execute permissions on stored procedure almost constantly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, permissions, powerbi, powerbi-report-server

I have PowerBi Server (Jan 2019) installed on my server. I can see from the default trace that that the PowerBi Service account `NT SERVICE\PowerBIReportServer` is granting execute permissions on a stored procedure `ExtendEditSessionLifetime` to the `RSExecRole` (within the `ReportServer` database):

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[ExtendEditSessionLifetime] TO RSExecRole
```

This is happening frequently many times during the hour, most hours (around 50 times an hour) there doesn't seem to a pattern that I can see and I can't find any documentation online about what the stored procedure does. I can't see anything obvious in the PowerBI logfiles or the event viewer either.

What could be causing this (or is it intended behaviour?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked out what is happening here.  tl/dr - There was a missing batch separator between a stored procedure and the associated `GRANT` statement.

If I run:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.sql_modules 
WHERE definition LIKE '%GRANT EXECUTE ON \[dbo\].\[ExtendEditSessionLifetime\] TO RSExecRole%' ESCAPE '\'
```

I can see stored procedures that have that grant statement within them.

This returned one record and the definition field begins

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[ExtendEditSessionLifetime]      @EditSessionID varchar(32)......
```

If I navigate to this stored procedure in the object tree and right click and script it out, I can see text of the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[ExtendEditSessionLifetime]
    -- params
AS
BEGIN
    --code
END
    
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[ExtendEditSessionLifetime] TO RSExecRole
GO
```

I wasn't aware of this but it seems that when you create a stored procedure, you can place a `GRANT` after the `END` and it becomes part of the definition (I thought it had to be part of the `BEGIN .... END` construct (when there is one)

Therefore, every time `ExtendEditSessionLifetime` is run, it is re-granting permissions to `RSExecRole`.